# Get Lua runtime errors inside the script

Tags: lua

I have no idea how to debug scripts efficiently. I need a stack output like Python's but by default Lua/C doesn't have this. I don't know how to enable that. Or simply, how to get the error output from the script?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are probably looking for a combination of xpcall and debug.traceback. You can use xpcall to pass it an error handler and the use debug.traceback to get the stack trace:

```
function functionThatMayFail()
  error('Failed')
end
local success, result = xpcall(functionThatMayFail,
  function(err) return debug.traceback(err) end)
print(success, result)
```

This code will print:

```
false   xpcall.lua:2: Failed
stack traceback:
    xpcall.lua:6: in function <xpcall.lua:6>
    [C]: in function 'error'
    xpcall.lua:2: in function <xpcall.lua:1>
    [C]: in function 'xpcall'
    xpcall.lua:5: in main chunk
    [C]: ?
```

Comment: How can it deal with a function with more than 1 argument?

Comment: I'm using xpcall with an anon func (let it call other functions). It now works exactly what I want. Thanks!

Comment: A bit late, but you don't even need that inner function. 

    function functionThatMayFail()
       error('Failed')
    end
    local success, result = xpcall(functionThatMayFail, debug.traceback)
    print(success, result)

[See the last example at Nick Gammon's nice documentation about LUA.](http://www.gammon.com.au/scripts/doc.php?lua=xpcall)

Answer (score 0):

The Lua interpreter does produce error output by default. E.g. (I introduced a typo into this script):

```
$ lua random.lua 
lua: random.lua:6: attempt to call global 'xists' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
    random.lua:6: in main chunk
    [C]: ?
```

Can you clarify what you're trying to do or maybe better what isn't happening that you expected to happen, in terms of error output?

Comment: This won't work for me because I implemented a wrapper for my functions inside the main program. It's can't be used outside the program itself. Sometimes there are too many errors happening together, most of them are easy to solve so it's unnecessary to post out.